# How to get data from power bi tile in power apps?

Tags: powerbi, powerapps

I am developing a power app where a power BI tile is embedded. I can filter power BI data.

Now I want to load a form from power bi tile data selection. Suppose, user click on a row of tile data. I want to get which row has been clicked by user. is it possible to get ?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.